# addEventListener control

Tags: javascript, html, css

(Sorry for screenshots, for some reason it's not letting me to upload code)

Implementing "addEventListener" in my JS.

```
console.log(event.target)
```

Depending on which part of the button you press I get different results
(because of the logo or the actual button).
How do I make the JS ignore the logo and return only the button element?

```html
<div class="images">
    <div class="pic_01">
        <div class="column">
            <img class="img" id="1" src="photo/1.jpg">
            <button id="button1" class="like_button" type="button">
                <img class="like_logo" src="images/like.png">&nbsp;
                <div>2
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add 4 spaces in every line

Comment: what do you mean? spaces where?

Comment: There is a missing addEventListener() part in your code. We can't say anything without it

Answer (score 0):

you should use event.currentTarget instead of event.target.
You will get the node that the event listener was attached to, even if a child node was clicked.

You can recursively check the parent node to see if the button or child element was clicked.

```
 document.querySelector('.images').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var button = handleClickEvent(event.target, event.currentTarget);
        if (button) {
            alert('clicked button');
        }
    }, false);

    function handleClickEvent(node, targetNode) {
        if (node.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
            return node;
        }
        else if (node == targetNode) {
            return;
        }
        return handleClickEvent(node.parentNode, targetNode);
    }
```

Comment: addEventListener attached to div with class image.
Can't attach to anything.
if i use event.currentTarget it returns always div with class image

Comment: if you can't change the event listener to the button element, you can try this